# Grammar of なにを思ったのか

Tags: grammar

I would like to know the grammar behind なにを思ったのか in the sentence

> そしてダクネスの頭に、**何を思ったのか**石を投げつけそのままタルの中に身を隠した。
>
> Then she pitched a stone at
> Darkness's head and ducked down into the barrel.

The translated sentence does not seem to take into account 何を思ったのか.

Does the 何を思ったのか石 mean "a stone or something I thought was a stone" ?

Comment: I'd like to see a fuller explanation, but there is an answer here on precisely this sentence: https://hinative.com/ja/questions/17971832

Comment: thanks for the link, unfortunately he gives only the meaning (which is already good) but I am more interested in understanding the structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is

> そしてダクネスの頭に、(**彼女は**)何を思ったのか、石を投げつけそのままタルの中に身を隠した.

The part is translated as "What did she think?", "I wonder what she thought". That is "the speaker couldn't understand the reason why she pitched a stone at Darkness's head and ducked down into the barrel."